# Is there a uniformly most powerful yet exact test for independence of two categorical variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test, neyman-pearson-lemma

I know that uniformly most powerful tests have to be based on the likelihood ratios as test statistic, which is not the case for the Fisher exact test. Nevertheless couldn't I use the G2 test metric, but calculate & tabulate its test statistic numerically for all relevant small numbers instead of approximating it by $\chi_1$?

Comment: It would help if you explained your setup properly. Are you talking about the independence of two categorical variables?

Comment: yes. updated question

Comment: For small sample sizes, you generally shouldn't rely on asymptotic approximations so you shouldn't really care about what test, asymptotically has the most power. Simulations are better.

Comment: It's something that has been discussed for 2 x 2 tables.  For example, with Fisher's, Barnard's, Boschloo's tests.

Comment: I guess to get a better answer, you'd have to explain what are proposing with a little more detail.  That is, it's easy enough to calculate the *G* statistic (log-likelihood statistic) for a contingency table.  But then how would you calculate the *p*-value ?

Comment: Beyond 2x2 things can be complicated, especially with small samples. For example, you don't have one-sided tests (no Karlin-Rubin theorem for example), you're dealing with omnibus alternatives and generally there's no UMP test.

Comment: Further, biased tests are common with omnibus alternatives. I expect this is the case with the G test (it's certainly so for the chi-squared)